# pdf.js how to add loading spinner while pdf document not started loading yet

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, frontend, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js for render pdf files on page.
In my case I am not just load existing pdf, but at first I convert different types of files on backend to pdf(which takes a few seconds), then send resulting pdf in response. Built-in loading bar appears only while bytes tranfers from backend, unfortunatly during conversion user sees only grey screen without any activity like on attached screenshot.
How can I add something like spinner or whatever element while loading not started yet?

[image: grey screen]